# Failed Error: Private key missing from key store. Can not establish the signing identity for user admin

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Generating the public key but not able to generate the private key of admin user while registering a new user through REST services in blockchain network and also getting below mentioned error.

> Error:Failed Error: Private key missing from key store. Can not
>   establish the signing identity for user admin.

**Followed the below steps :**

1. Created a network in hyperledger fabric.
2. Created new a node application to publish the rest services by
       referring the existing "balance-transfer" application.
3. Then started the node application.
4. Testing the rest services url in postman tool.

Getting the above mentioned error while testing the url http://localhost:4000/users in Postman tool.

**Error at code level:**
app.js--->helper.js

```
let adminUserObj = await client.setUserContext({username: admins[0].username, password: admins[0].secret});
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the folders holding key-value store for organizations -> fabric-client-kv-* from the balance-transfer fabric sample.

rm -rf fabric-client-kv-*

Then create the network again. This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: There is fabric-client-kv-* pattern folder in /tmp directory also, do we need to delete that everytime whenever we restart the network?

Comment: Thank you for the response, always I am removing the folders holding key-value store for organizations -> fabric-client-kv-* from the balance-transfer fabric sample while restarting the network. But still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to restart the network completely? (by using the "runApp.sh" script for that?) Take a look inside this script to the restartNetwork() function, where the "fabric-client-kv-org" folders in your balance-transfer folder are removed.

Does it work?